# Pass in a reference to a map in C++

Tags: c++, stl, reference, pass-by-reference

I'm looking to pass in a reference to a map and NOT have map place it somewhere else - Here's what I'm working with:

```
map<string, Node> _neighbors; // Instance Variable


Node& neighbor(Node& neighbor) {
    cout << "HOST: "<< neighbor.host() << " ADDRESS: " << &neighbor << endl;
    string key = this->getKey(neighbor);

    if(!_neighbors.count(key)) {
        _neighbors[key] = neighbor;
        cout << "HOST (AFTER): "<< _neighbors[key].host() << " ADDRESS: " << &_neighbors[key] << endl;
        neighbor.neighbor(*this);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Output: 
When I call `n1.neighbor(n2); // n1 is a Node with host=1 and n2 is a Node with host=2`

HOST: 2 ADDRESS: 0x7fff5fbfe580

HOST (AFTER): 2 ADDRESS: 0x100100128

Comment: ... And **why** exactly do you need this?

Comment: I needed to be able to pull things out of neighbors, update them and have them reflected in the originally instantiated node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store references in an STL container.  Containers store objects and references are not objects (in addition, the objects stored in a container must be assignable, and references are not assignable).

You'll want to use a map of pointers:

```
std::map<std::string, Node*>
```

Also, beware of ownership issues.  You need to make sure that the objects are not destroyed until everyone that has a reference to them is done using them.  If you have objects used in multiple places, consider using a shared ownership smart pointer, like `shared_ptr`, to manage object lifetimes for you.  Manual resource management in C++ is fraught with peril and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Even if you don't have objects used in multiple places it's (almost) always better to use smart pointers within STL containers.  Because a native pointer has no destructor mechanism to free it, any of the container-based "removal" operations can have an implicit memory leak unless the programmer is aware of this and is very careful, i.e. no use of algorithms that remove ranges, etc.

Comment: @dlanod:  Quite right.  I assumed that the map here either was not responsible for owning object lifetimes or shared responsibility with something else; that may have been a poor assumption.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I think I'm going to try a different approach because I'm really not good at this stuff. *One question: I know parameters get copied in by value, but do methods return values or references?*

Comment: @Matt: Unless you explicitly say to use a reference (using the `&` after the type name), you get value semantics.  So, a function that returns a `T&` returns a reference to a `T`, while a function that just returns a `T` returns a `T` object by value.

Comment: @Matt:  One caveat:  you can hide a reference in a typedef, so you could have `typedef T& TRef`, then a function `TRef Foo()` will return a `T&`.  Just be careful with typedefs.